# Agile - Dealing with changing requirements for already implemented features

Tags: project-management, agile

In a recent meeting with my client, we discovered we missed out on a Detail of User Story, that has already been implemented several iterations before.

The new requirement is not only an additional Feature but changed behaviour.

The original User Story goes like:
*"Can View XYZ"*

The new request however goes like:
*"Can View XYZ but if B then XYZ must look like ABC"*

Shall i consider this a Bug or a New User Story, or should i simply reopen the old user Story and edit it to account for the new request?
What is the "best-practice", what are pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, since it is a new requirement, treat it as a new feature request. Definitely not a bug.

EDIT: Since it is not clear who missed the detail either you or the customer, you can take both ways. If you forgot about it, then it is your bug. If the customer forgot to tell about it, then it depends. If it is a little fix, you can reopen the old story. If it is much work to be done, make it a new one.

P.S. Does it really matter how you do it? The point is just implement it like the customer asks, regardless of your internal terminology.

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle-guy.com](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/files/2009/02/bug-feature.jpg))</sub>

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/dratz/1045336659/ :)

Comment: ok, but should i make it a new User Story?

Comment: thanks, excellent explanation! That way i could also track if I forget features (->lack of description on my side) or if my Customers like to forget to tell me what they want :-) I will mark correct answer in next 24h

Comment: The question is: Does tracking have or provide value? If not, it's waste.

Comment: yup, it does, i learn how to deal with them, when to ask the right questions etc :-)

Answer (score 4):

A Bug, a new User Story, reopening the old Story... is that really important? In any case, your customer is asking for a feature that is currently not implemented. So, as long as you can estimate its size and as long as he can prioritize it, it doesn't really matter how you call the way you capture the needs.

So, unless you have to deal with specific contractual constraints, just pick one solution, estimate the size and let the customer prioritize it (personally, I'd create a new user story).

Comment: it's about the "best-practice" the pro and cons of each approach (added that to the question), thanks for your thoughts

Comment: The best practice is to satisfy the customer, to welcome change, to deliver working software, etc. http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html :)

Answer (score 0):

I would edit the old story to document the modification. Otherwise you may have contradictions between the new story and the old one.

This can hardly be considered as a defect (or bug) if the customer changed its mind.

Be pragmatic: estimate it, schedule it and implement it.

Comment: well, they didnt change their mind, they simply forgot to tell me (see above, ive edited the question to make that clear)

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. But I insist on documenting it, especially since you seem to maintain the stories electronically (reopen and edit). Otherwise you can have contradictions between your stories.

Comment: Who cares if an open story has contradictions with a finished/closed one? Documenting the contradiction is pure "Cover Your Ass", it's adding more waste to some previous waste. It doesn't sound really lean/agile to me.

Comment: In a pure agile environment, that's right. But we do not know the context here - it seems the stories are not kept on index cards but in an electronic document. If this document is used in any way, it might be better to update the initial story.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this should count as the old story. Your team should report reduced throughput (velocity) because of these changing requirements, especially if the original feature has not already shipped.

Comment: You will loose tracability if you do major user story makeover. Especially if the 'new' user story will not get actually implemented (low priority, overridden etc.) and the older implementation will still stick around.